# Trying to identify a sci-fi TV anthology - Fish catches man

Tags: story-identification, tv

Early 80's to early 90's TV episodes, short science fiction stories in the style of 'Ray Bradbury Theatre' and 'Amazing Stories'.

I remember a fat guy fishing by a pond who catches a bluegill. Then, out of nowhere a red apple rolls close to him. As he bites into it, a huge hook pulls him into the water. End of short.

Answer (score 15):

I would say the answer is Vincent Price's 1986 short horror story anthology *[Escapes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091016/)*.

In the opening segment, a teenager receives a strange tape and decides to watch it. Vincent Price appears and announces that we are going to see six horror stories. The first, "A Little Fishy" (called "Something's Fishy" in the list of contents), involves a man out fishing on a lake. He sees an apple on the shore and decides to eat it, but it turns out the mysterious fruit is not quite what it seems and the man winds up on a hook pulled into the water.

Comment: Damn good going, does it have a scene with a lab with an alarm going off, two scientists are running one falls and these two creatures catch them and one says( your it then they run off) ?

Comment: The entire show is available streaming online. A youtube search for Vincent Price Escapes will let you determine if this is what you are looking for. If it is, you can select the checkmark next to the answer I provided to accept this as the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 4):

There's a Dutch children's(!) book along the same lines, *De Vis en de Jongen* (*The Fish and the Boy*) by [Dolf Verroen](http://www.dolfverroen.nl/), with pictures by Ton Frederiks.

[image: Cover of "De Vis en de Jongen by Dolf Verroen]

It's no longer for sale, but [you can read it (in Dutch) on the author's website](http://www.dolfverroen.nl/vis%20bl1.html) ("omslaan" means "turn the page").

It's from 1979, so there is a (however slight) possibility of it being the inspiration of the short.

Comment: Unlikely that they're related, but still damn interesting.

Comment: Morbid much for a childrens story? "Mag ik het piemeltje?" vroeg de vis die de jongen gevangen had. "Want dat is het lekkerst." That is seriously creepy. I get that the author was making a strong point, but the boys piemltje? Really?

Answer (score 4):

There was an earlier BW short film (1960s?) about a fisherman on a beach who bites into a sandwich and is dragged into the ocean. I believe it was shot at Ocean Beach in San Francisco. It’s much better than “Sometning Fishy.” I believe I saw it at the Playhouse in Sausalito with “The Birds” when it was new.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a quick read, there's an earlier short story by Robert Sheckley that deals with the same subject: "**[Fishing Season](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58554)**", published in 1953.

People are vanishing from a suburban area as...fishy products appear in supermarkets (their labels have small errors or differences); meanwhile, the protagonist's father-in-law keeps going fishing in a nearby stream.
In the finale everything is explained: but long before the ending the reader has already grasped what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Desserts. An ocean creature gets its victims off the shores by "fishing" for them. It's on Spooks and Creeps DVD. Fantastic short films!

Comment: Can you provide a link or a screenshot?

Comment: Whilst a good brief overview, could you [edit] this to better explain how it matches the description given in the question?